# Bash script for monitoring logs based upon last update time

Tags: bash

I have a directory on a RHEL 6 server where logs are being written as below. As you can see there are 4 logs already written within 1 minute. I just want to write a script which can check in every 15 minute (Cron ) & if log files are not updating then send an email alert like " Adapter is in hang status, Restart Required". I know basic linux commands & knowledge of crons. This is how i am trying

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root    root   11M Oct  6 00:32  Adapter.log.3
-rw-r--r-- 1 root    root   11M Oct  6 00:32  Adapter.log.2
-rw-r--r-- 1 root    root   10M Oct  6 00:32  Adapter.log.1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root    root  6.3M Oct  6 00:32  Adapter.log

$ ll Adapter.log >/tmp/test.txt
$ cat test.txt | awk '{print $6,$7,$8}'
Oct 6 03:10
```

Now how can i get the time of same log file after 15 minutes, so that i can compare the time difference and write a script to send the alert.

Comment: Welcome to SO! To increase the chance of answers: Make the question more concrete. You are now only stating what you want. Not really asking anything. Its not clear if you dont know bash, how to register a cron job, or how to send email. Whats the question? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: `are not updating` - what does that mean? I would copy all files - wait 15 minutes - use `diff -r` to compare all files - if any difference then something else something

Answer (score 1):

Given description, looks like you timestamp can be checked every 15 minutes.

1. If file was updated in last 15 minutes, do nothing
2. If file was updated 15 to 30 minutes ago, send email alert
3. If file was updated 30 minutes ago, do nothing, as error was already reported on previous cycle

Consider placing the following into cron, on 15 minute interval:

```
find /path/to/log/Adapter.log* -mmin +15 -mmin -30 | xargs -L1 send-alert
```

This solution will work on most situations. However, it's worth noting that if the system load is very high, cron execution may be delayed, impacting the age test. In those cases, extra file to store the last test time is needed.

Comment: -rw-r--r-- 1 root    root  6.3M Oct  6 00:32  Adapter.log

See above timestamp. My question is if log file got stuck at this moment then how can i get an alert. I mean what command i need to use to compare the current timestamp and the timestamp after 15 minutes.

old timestamp < new time ( Fater 15 minutes time) > do nothing
old timestamp = new timestamp ( after 15 minutes) > Send alert

Comment: Given the script execute every 15 minutes, and if the process hang, the alert will occur on the (single) run that executed between hang+15 and hang+30